# Error while updating Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: apt, updates

[Update 2]
Please check image UbuntuError_1.

[image]

---

[Update 1]
I tried to follow the steps to disable the IPv6,and then run `sudo apt-get update` again. Still no luck :

O/P:

```
amit@peace-aks:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for amit: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for amit: 
Err:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                 
  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                   
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                        
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
amit@peace-aks:~$
```

---

[Main Post]
I am getting the attached error while runnig **`sudo apt-get update`**

```
amit@peace-aks:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for amit: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for amit: 
Err:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                              
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::1c). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                 
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                                 
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::1c). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
amit@peace-aks:~$
```

Running **`ubuntu-support-status`** gives this result :

```
amit@peace-aks:~$ ubuntu-support-status
Support status summary of 'peace-aks':


You have 2476 packages (100.0%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 0 packages (0.0%) that are unsupported
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Please provide full output of `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Thanks ! Added the full output of sudo apt-get update in the description.

Comment: Tried to follow the steps to disable ipV6. No luck still

Comment: Unable to add long comments here, so adding in my main post...

Comment: Can you access any internet resources from this system with browser? Is it online?

Comment: I think you have network issue. Try changing the server.

Comment: Yes, I can access internet via browser @N0rbert

Comment: Then try to select geographically nearest mirror from *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) and retry.

Comment: @Kulfy, I am not able to change the server. It's giving error - Please check your internet connection.

Comment: @N0rbert, please see the o/p for softwarepproperties-gtk -d, in the [Update 2] section in the problem description.

Comment: :-( nothing working....